# rails state_machine doesn't change state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I'm trying to adopt state_machine to enable my users to have a state within the signup process in a Rails 3.1.3 app. I'm trying to make a very simple case but I can't change its state by means of an event. After rereading the documentation sevreal times, I haven't found what's wrong.

My User ActiveRecord model is:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  name               :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
#  encrypted_password :string(255)
#  salt               :string(255)
#  admin              :boolean         default(FALSE)
#  notify_followers   :boolean         default(TRUE)
#  state              :string(255)
#

# MME per a utilitzar les Hash functions
require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :password # MME nomes dona acces a la instance var @password que no es guarda a la BBDD

  # MME si es posa, atributs (columnes) als que es podrà accedir via ActiveRecord
  attr_accessible   :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin, :notify_followers
  # MME validacions
  validates :name, :presence => true,
                   :length=> {maximum: 50}

  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}

  validates :password, :presence => true,
                       :confirmation => true,   # crea un atribut password_confirmation i a la vegada confirma que sigui igual que password
                       :length => { :within => 6..40 }

    # validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true   # MME aixo exigigeix que al crear es passi un :password_confirmation, doncs amb nomes
                              #   l'anterior validator sol, pot crearse un usuari si no es passa :password_confirmation

  before_save :encrypt_password

  # MME a l'esborrar un User s'esborren tb els seus Micropost
  has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy

 # MME Afegim respostes als usuaris
  has_many :replies, :class_name => 'Micropost',
                     :foreign_key => "in_reply_to",
                     :inverse_of => :replied_user,
                     :dependent => :destroy

  # User com a seguidor (follower)

  # te molts :relationships apuntant-lo amb la clau follower_id. Si el User s'elimina tots aquests Relationship tambe seran eliminats.
  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id",
                           :dependent => :destroy

  # te molts seguits via :relationships als que s'apunta via :followed_id  (inferit gracies a :followed, que apunta a la vegada als User)
  has_many :following, :through => :relationships,
                       :source => :followed

  # User com a seguit (followed)

  # te molts :reverse_relationships apuntant-lo amb la clau followed_id. Si el User s'elimina tots aquests Relationship tambe seran eliminats.
  has_many :reverse_relationships, :class_name => "Relationship",
                                   :foreign_key => "followed_id",
                                   :dependent => :destroy

  # te molts seguidors via :reverse_relationships als que s'apunta via :follower_id  (inferit gracies a :follower, que apunta a la vegada als User)
  has_many :followers, :through => :reverse_relationships

  # Torna els microposts dels usuaris seguits per un user, per exemple:
  #    usr=User.find(12)
  #    usr.following_microposts
  # (no el faig anar finalment: Micropost.from_users_followed_by(user) ho he implementat sense aquests metode perque
  # em falten els microposts del propi user) 
  has_many :following_microposts, :through => :following, 
                                  :source => :microposts

  # Si n'hi ha, te un password_reminder
  has_one :password_reminder

  # Torna l'User de l'email si el password es correcte
  def self.authenticate(email, submited_pwd)
    if usr = find_by_email(email)
      usr.has_password?(submited_pwd) ? usr : nil
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  # Torna l'User del id si el salt es correcte (s'utilitza per les sessions)
  def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == salt) ? user : nil
  end

  # verifica si el password correspon a l'User
  def has_password?(submited_pwd)
    self.encrypted_password == encrypt(submited_pwd)
  end

  def feed
    #Micropost.from_users_followed_by self
    # Microposts from
    #   self
    #   self.following
    #   self.replies
    Micropost.not_messages.from_users_followed_by_or_in_reply_to self
  end

  # Is usr being followed by self?
  def following? usr
    following.include? usr
    # MME segons el tutorial seria
    #relationships.find_by_followed_id(followed)
  end

  def follow! usr
    relationships.create! :followed_id => usr.id
  end

  def unfollow! usr
    relationships.find_by_followed_id(usr.id).destroy if following?(usr)
  end

  def replies_to(usr, content)
    microposts.create :content=>content, :in_reply_to=>usr.id, :private=>false
  end

  def sends_to(usr, content)
    microposts.create :content=>content, :in_reply_to=>usr.id, :private=>true
  end

  def messages_to usr
    microposts.messages.where(:in_reply_to => usr.id)
  end

  def messages_from usr
    usr.microposts.messages.where(:in_reply_to => self.id)
  end

  def messages_to_or_from usr
    Micropost.messages.between usr, self
  end
  alias conversation_with messages_to_or_from

  # MME generates a unique login name for a user
  def pseudo_login_name
    name.downcase.split.join("_")+"_"+ id.to_s
  end

  # MME generates a password reminder if it doesn't yet exist
  def generate_password_reminder
    #PasswordReminder.find_or_create_by_user_id_and_token :user_id=>self.id,
    #                                                     :token=>SecureRandom.hex(32)
    create_password_reminder!(:token=>SecureRandom.hex(32)) unless password_reminder
  end

  # MME removes its password reminder if exists
  def remove_password_reminder
    password_reminder.delete if password_reminder
  end

  # finds a user from a token (password reminder to change password)
  def self.find_by_token(token)
    pr=PasswordReminder.find_by_token(token, :include=>:user)
    pr.user if pr
  end

  # MME finds a user from a pseudo_login_name
  # first tries to get it from an id
  # last tries to get it from a name
  def self.find_by_pseudo_login_name(pln)
    nam=pln.split("_")
    id = nam.last.to_i
    if id>0 # First attempt: if it exists an id as the last part off the pln 
      User.find_by_id(id)
    else # Second attempt: try to generate a name from a pln
      User.find_by_name(nam.map(&:capitalize).join(" "))
    end
  end

  ## MME state_machine per a fer la inscripcio en passos
  state_machine :initial => :pending do
    event :email_confirm do
      transition :pending => :email_confirmed
    end
  end


  # FUNCIONS PRIVADES
  private

    def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)  # self.salt resets everytime user changes its password
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)   # password refers to self.password
    end

    def make_salt
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest "#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}"
    end

    def encrypt(str)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest "#{salt}--#{str}"
    end

end
```

Of course, I've already done a migration to enable User to acomodate a state machine

```
$ rails g migration AddStateToUser state:string
$ rake db:migrate
```

and checked out that User really responds to a state attribute from rails console.

The problem arises when I try to simply change the state of the machine like in this console session log:

```
1.9.2-p290 :006 > u=User.find 1
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Marcel", email: "mme@gmail.com", created_at: "2012-04-29 10:43:42", updated_at: "2012-04-29 10:43:42", encrypted_password: "d08c12c1cfb51fe5732f5e423b94dfdcaca1a1eb67821e3e37a...", salt: "78dfbecdfd4ffdd1fbcac5a878529b91a5200d563ebe3af23cf...", admin: false, notify_followers: true, state: "pendant"> 
1.9.2-p290 :007 > u.state
 => "pendant" 
1.9.2-p290 :008 > u.email_confirm
   (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('mme@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
 => false 
1.9.2-p290 :009 > u.state
 => "pendant"
```

as you may notice, from the last command, my user hasn't changed his state to :email_confirmed as it was suposed to. I also don't understand the SQL query that's being done by the way. It seems suspicious to me.

More on that. If I try to update a User model as usual, the same strange SQL query appears and doesn't update the model. This session log shows that:

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > u=User.find 1
  User Load (55.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<User id: 1, name: "Marcel Massana", email: "xaxaupua@gmail.com", created_at: "2012-04-29 19:32:26", updated_at: "2012-04-29 20:44:10", encrypted_password: "2ef5fec3287e2b26600521488060f698abed387e18e395d1331...", salt: "fa4d3ebb44c00237b66c95cc75ed5d1cda3b6e1535082def2a8...", admin: true, notify_followers: true, state: "pending"> 
1.9.2-p290 :002 > u.update_attributes(:name=>"Marcel")
   (0.1ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('xaxaupua@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
 => false
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong? Any hint?

(of course I coud change user.state="email_confirmed" but then why to use state_machine?)

Comment: the problem is in your `email_confirm`. It returns false, and that query is odd. Why it's doing `"users"."id" != 1` ?

Comment: well ... email_confirm is defined in state_machine simply to change from :pendant to :email_confirmed, no more than that, as you can see at the beginning of the post.

Comment: are you using some gem for session, like devise?

Comment: no, i've made my own authentication following Rails Tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.0) without any problem.

Comment: Have you defined model validations?  If so perhaps one of them is causing the problem.

Comment: I've updated the model with its validations. I cannot imagine what's the problem. Another thing I noticed is that some of my tests stoped working after the simple fact of adding the state machine. If I remove it, all my tests continue working.

Comment: please post the complete code, including user.rb and user_spec.rb (I mean the unit test file)

Comment: I've completed the User model. I don't use RSpec, I use Test::Unit. Nonetheless, I have noticed that the only tests that fail are those that try try to update a user.

Comment: More on that: If I try to update a User, the same strange behaviour occurs. It doesn't update anything and the rare SQL query shows again. 8-|. See it all on the updated post.

Answer (score 2):

The extra SQL query is a result of your validation:

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

It checks the DB to see if a different User (`id != 1`) with that (lower-cased) email already exists.

Answer (score 1):

OK, seems I've found what's happening:

Everytime I make a change in the `state_machine`, such as, for instance:

```
$ u.email_confirm
```

`state_machine` internally calls `User#update_attributes` on `u` (my User instance) with `state` attribute as the only one to be updated. This means that `User#save` method is called and, BTW, prior to that validations are also checked. As far as other attributes are not updated, some validations may prohibit to save `u`, so `u.state` isn't obviously changed.

To overcome that, I simply put all my validations within a state. To sum up:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    state_machine :initial => :pending do

       event :email_confirm do
         transition :pending => :email_confirmed
       end

      state :pending do

        validates :name, :presence => true,
                         :length=> {maximum: 50}

        validates :email, :presence => true,
                          :format => { :with => /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i },
                          :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false}

        validates :password, :presence => true,
                             :confirmation => true,
                             :length => { :within => 6..40 }
      end
    end
    ...
  end
```

validations are always called just before save, so, when transitioning from `:pending` to `:email_confirmed`, `u.state` has already a value `:email_confirmed` and no validations are performed.

Additionally, the strange (to me at least) SQL query

```
SELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('xaxaupua@gmail.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
```

is performed only when validations are enabled. If I disable validations this query isn't performed. Don't know why ActiveRecord performs that query. Despite this is not a problem for me right now, I would thank anybody that throws a little bit of light over that issue or point me to any link that explains that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

By default validations are performed for :create, and :update events on a Model.  I had a similar issue with state_machine. My solution was to simply remove validation on the :update event since the email and name attribs are read-only after the record is created.  For example :

```
validates(:name, :presence => true,
        :length => { :maximum => 50},
        :uniqueness =>true,
        :on => :create)
validates(:email, :presence => true,
        :format => {:with => email_regex},
        :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false},
        :on => :create)
validates(:password, :presence => true,
        :confirmation => true,
        :length => { :within => 6..40},
        :if => :password)
```

Note, that the password validation is performed IF the password attrib has changed. This also avoids the state_machine issue you experience.  If you provide Users access to changing name, and email you could apply the same logic to those validators too.